# netCDF make command test?

Tags: linux, netcdf

I need to install **netCDF** and **graDs** in linux to be able to run another program ,
but I am not familiar with them , I have just configured and make them but I didn't get any message which contains : successfully make or sth like that.

output of Make :

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples/C'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples/C'
Making all in CDL
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples/CDL'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples/CDL'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0/examples'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nazanin/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.0'
```

Does it mean that the "make" command worked properly,or there is sth wrong? and is there any "test" for it?

I am a very beginner in Ubuntu linux.

Thank you.

Comment: @Rahul R Dhobi thank you so much rahul

Comment: Run make install and type netcdf-bin command in terminal if you find this command then you have compiled netcdf properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better for you to install **netCDF** and **graDs** by following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netcdf*
sudo apt-get install grads
```

Comment: :thanks, but how can i be sure of getting all that is required?should i paste here the log file?

Comment: Setting up libdap11:i386 (3.11.1-15) ...
Setting up libdapclient3:i386 (3.11.1-15) ...
Setting up libgrib2c0d:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libshp1:i386 (1.2.10-7) ...
Setting up libudunits2-0:i386 (2.1.23-4) ...
Setting up libgeotiff2 (1.3.0+dfsg-3.2)
Setting up grads (2:2.0.1-1build1)
Processing triggers for libc-bin

Comment: Yes this means grads is installed now

Comment: : rahul i have a manual which tells to link a file in another script and then compile it , can you help me how to link a file in a script? thank you

Comment: Please post question regarding your issue with full detail

Comment: rahul i asked it in another question , will u pls look at it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are compiling with `autotools`, you would typically use `make check` to run the tests.  Please note that there is a known failure in the `DAP` tests for versions 4.3.0 through 4.3.1.1, related to a change in the Unidata netcdf test servers.

I will mention that netcdf 4.3.0 is fairly old.  The latest stable release, `v4.3.1.1` may be downloaded here:

http://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/releases

There is also a release candidate for the next release, `v4.3.2` available, and a second release candidate should be available later today or tomorrow.  There have been a number of bug fixes since 4.3.0 that you may be interested in :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes your make work correctly.

To test, try make check.

To install, try make install.